# I want to show animation in my android activity inside the dialog

Tags: android, animation, dialog

I want to show a dialog box having animation played guiding the user to perform operations. You can have a look at naukari.com android app where it is been shown. I don't know what the animation is like is it a swf or something gif or etc? please guide me for the same. If I could get what kind of resource is used to play that animation I can think on the similar lines. The link below shows the image representing the naukari.com app image.

[animation inside a dialog](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nxvGF.jpg)